# Proving that monotonously rising functions on $[0,1]$ have at most countable points of discontinuity.

Tags: measure-theory

The answer is given with an idea about looking at the "jumps" a "jump" constituting ($x_0-$point of discontinuity) $$s=\lim_{x\to x_0+}f(x)-\lim_{x\to x_0-}f(x)$$

Since $[0,1]$ is in question the largest possible "jump" is $f(1)-f(0).$ because the function is rising on $[0,1]$.

The following is unclear(given):

If we have a "jump" of length $\alpha$, then the number of points  this can occur at will be **at most** is $$int \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{\alpha}$$ int- integerpart function. Can anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as projected onto the $y$-axis. Then $f(1)-f(0)$ is the total amount $f$ traverses upwards on it. Suppose the number of times your function jumps by an amount of $\alpha$ is given by $x$. Then from this it follows that
$$x\alpha \leq^!f(1)-f(0)$$
because otherwise you would get a contradiction because $f$ cannot increase further on the $y$-axis than $f(1)-f(0)$. But dividing the above inequality by $\alpha$ and applying the integer-part function (because you can only jump an integer number of times) gives precisely your claim.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since it is monotically increasing, every discontinuity must be due to the fact that:

$$\lim_{x^+} \neq \lim_{x^-}.$$

Now, for every point of discontinuity $x$, you will then be able to assign a rational between $\lim_{x^+}$ and $\lim_{x^-}$. Again, since it is monotonically increasing, this map must be an injection. Therefore, $\# D \leq \# \mathbb{Q}$, where $D=\{\text{discontinuities}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

For each point of discontinuity $x_0$ consider the open interval $I_{x_0}=(sup\{f(x)|x<x_0\},inf\{f(x)|x>x_0\})$. Prove these intervals are non-empty and that if $x_0$ and $x_1$ are discontinuity points then $I_{x_0}$ and $I_{x_1}$ are disjoint. Therefore the discontinuity points are in direct bijection with a set of disjoint open intervals. What is the maximum number of these we can have?